# What should be done about [livegraph]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [livegraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/livegraph) tag, according to its wiki, refers to a Java framework for displaying graphs which update in real time. There are 5 questions with the tag, of which exactly one actually has anything to do with the Java framework mentioned in the wiki. It's not a problem for someone (perhaps myself) to edit the tag off the remaining four questions, but since it seems highly susceptible to misuse, is there something that should be done to prevent that in the future, like renaming the tag? Or should it be removed entirely, since there seems to be very little use for it?